# storing std::auto_ptr in a container

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

It is said that we should always use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::auto_ptr` and it is said that we were not able to store a `auto_ptr` in a container But consider this example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    std::vector< std::auto_ptr<int> > v;
    std::auto_ptr<int> u(new int(5));
    v.push_back(u);
    v.push_back(std::auto_ptr<int>(new int(10)));

    typedef std::vector< std::auto_ptr<int> >::iterator v_ap_it;
    for(v_ap_it beg = v.begin(), e = v.end(); beg != e; ++beg)
        std::cout << **beg << " ";



    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program runs fine. I've tested it on vC++ 6.0 and it works fine but doesn't run on C++11 and C++14 ! So how could it be not possible to store it in a container? 
* does this mean VC++ 6.0 is erroneous? I think so because it a buggy IDE.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` was a mistake. Let it die in peace.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I don't think so. Because back days when there was no alternative it is was something important.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa `std::unique_ptr` is better in every sense. And `std::auto_ptr` was removed in C++17 in favor of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: The rationale:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1856.html#20.4.5%20-%20Class%20template%20auto_ptr

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Ok. in fact this code doesn't compile on C++98 "cpp.sh". But it works on VC++ 6.0. Does this mean VC++ 6.0 is erroneous?